# Differences with element tree and xpath

Tags: python, html, parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to find some nodes in an element tree, but this seems to work differently depending on which implementation I use for parsing. That doesn't seem to be consistent with the documentation. Am I missing something?

```
In [52]: ElementTree.fromstring('<html><x /></html>').find('.//x')
Out[52]: <Element 'x' at 0x3008c10>
```

but:

```
In [59]: type(html5lib.parse('<html><x /></html>', treebuilder='lxml').find('.//x'))
Out[59]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

I've tried also html5lib with ElementTree, but that doesn't even seem to run parsing that would comply with documentation:

```
In [72]: parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder('etree', cElementTree))

In [73]: type(parser.parse('<html><x /></html>'))
Out[73]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

So how do I solve this? I can't continue using ElementTree directly since it doesn't parse some broken html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xpath()` seems to work:

```
>>> doc = html5lib.parse('<!doctype html><html><x /></html>', treebuilder='lxml')

>>> doc.xpath('.//*')
    [<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}head at 0x102c04a50>,
 <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}body at 0x102c04aa0>,
 <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}x at 0x102c04af0>]

>>> doc.xpath('.//html:x', namespaces={'html':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
    [<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}x at 0x102c04af0>]
```

It's rather strange, however, that `html5lib` assignes XHTML namespace to plain HTML.

Comment: And your comment led me to the solution: `html5lib.parse(..., namespaceHTMLElements=False).xpath('.//x')` works just fine :)